# Story about a boy who could control the weather and droughts

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

I read a fantasy book a very long time ago about a boy who could control the weather.  I believe he was poor and/or an outcast.  The enemy of the book was I believe a traveling salesman.  At the end I remember that everyone disregarded his ability and he didn't openly show off but rather used his ability to ease droughts.

Any ideas as to what this book is?

Comment: Avatar/ The Last Airbender?

Comment: No, I read this about 15 years ago.

Comment: Was there a book version?; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_of_Faith_(film)

Comment: It was a book, but not of that movie.  I think the salesmen may have been an illusionist, don't remember.  Magic wasn't prevalent in the book, in fact as I remember it was much like our world but this kid controlled the weather, and it gave him headaches when he did.

Comment: Thinking the book took place in slightly less modern times, the salesmen I believe sold "remedies" out of a horse drawn carriage.

Answer (score 4):

*[Dr. Dredd's Wagon of Wonders](http://www.librarything.com/work/94928/)* by Bill Brittain.

[image: *Dr. Dredd's Wagons of Wonders* book cover]

> The village of Coven Tree is again bedeviled. This time a mysterious impresario named Dr. Hugo Dredd offers to save the townspeople from a terrible drought by lending the services of young Bufu the Rainmaker—but at a dreadful cost.

The boy has headaches.

Answer (score 3):

That might be [*The Weathermonger*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Changes-Trilogy-1-Weathermonger/dp/0007140312) by Peter Dickinson, which is the first volume (first written, but last in internal chronology) of his *Changes* trilogy. The other volumes are *Heartsease* and *The Devil's Children*. It certainly has a boy who can control the weather as a protagonist, in a future Britain whose technology has been put back to medieval levels by (as it eventually turns out) magical means.

Comment: It was published 3 yrs ago and I definitely read this over a decade ago.

Comment: That's a reprint. _The Weathermonger_ was first published in 1969.